# How can i edit cells from a table using jQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I edit cell using Jquery. I want to edit cells not the entire row?

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    cellEdit: true,
    cellsubmit: 'remote',
    cellurl: "/proiecte/edit",
    onSelectCell : function(rowid,iCol,cellcontent,e)    {
          alert("Tralala");
    }


})
```

like [here](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html) but using jqgrid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally I figured it out !

```
colModel:[

        {name:'name',index:'name', width:'15%',title: false},

        {name:'finished',index:'finished', width:'2%',title: false},

        {name:'client',index:'client', width:'7%',title: false},

        {name:'manager',index:'manager', width:'7%',title: false,editable: true},

        {name:'etapaName',index:'etapaName', width:'5%',title: false},

        {name:'deadline',index:'deadline', width:'7%',title: false,editable: true},

        {name:'lastactivity',index:'lastactivity', width:'6%',title: false,editable: true},     

        {name:'estimated',index:'estimated', width:'3%',title: false,editable: true},     

        {name:'worked',index:'worked', width:'5%',title: false} ,

        {name:'remove',index:'remove', width:'2%', sortable:false}


    ],
```

The problem was the missing "editable:true" part !!!